# Error while creating the scheduler job from Visual Studio 2013 to Azure CSP Subscription

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I get below error while publishing webjob to Azure CSP subscription

**Error while creating the scheduler job from Visual Studio 2013 to Azure CSP Subscription**

\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.12\tools\webjobs.console.targets(110,5): Error : An error occurred while creating the WebJob schedule: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Notes   This error is specific to the Azure CSP Subscription.

> When I publish same WebJob to different Azure subscription that
>   supports classis ASM the WebJob and schedule both created
>   successfully.

Appreciate your help

Thanks,
Deepak

Comment: Are you able to use Azure CSP subscription to login in Azure powershell with this command `Login-AzureRmAccount`. Do you ensure that you can login in VS with CSP subscription? Please check that.

Comment: I'd like to know if your scheduled WebJobs run on free tier app service plan.

Comment: @Jambor-MSFT yes i am able to login to Azure using powershell command Login-AzureRmAccount.  I can login in VS 2013 with CSP subscription in Server Explorer but getting "This subscription is not supported by Server Explorer" on "Manage Microsoft Azure Subscriptions" window.

Comment: @FredHan-MSFT We have two PAYG subscriptions those support ASM since more than a year.  We never had any issues with publishing on both subscriptions. 
Recently we are trying to publish WebJob on Azure CSM subscription and we are getting this error.  The other difference is the CSP subscription is only ARM the classic ASM is not supported while accessing this subscription.

Comment: Can you publish the webjob without a schedule (e.g. on demand or triggered)?  There are some issues with creating schedules at times and you can set one up post-publish to get around them (search SO for some of them)

Comment: @bmoore-msft yes webjob without a schedule is getting published. This issue is only for creating scheduler job. We have two other Azure PAYG subscriptions and they support CSM.  We never had issue with them since last more than one year.  This issue is only while we are trying to publish to Azure subscription where only ARM is supported and it is CSP subscription.

Comment: I have resolved this issue by using CRON expression